# Trying to add text over image on Cargo

Tags: cargo-features

firstly, I DO NOT KNOW OR UNDERSTAND CODING!

I am using Cargo to design a website for my photography. I will split the pages into genres of my photography. I want to add the title of the page for images e.g. PORTRAITS over the top of the image of the portrait.

I have made the gallery, I have linked each image to a new page, but I cannot for the life of me get the caption or title of the page over the image!

Everything I have searched online is giving me coding answers and I just cannot do it!

Please someone help me out,

cheers

I tried to code but nothing changed.